# Aurelia Validation with i18n?

Tags: aurelia

Has anyone gotten Aurelia Validation to work with the i18n Plugin for multi-lingual error messages?  My app won't even start when I add in the code from the Aurelia documentation http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/12.

Here's my **main.js**:

```
import environment from './environment';
import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import {ValidationMessageProvider} from 'aurelia-validation';

//Configure Bluebird Promises.
//Note: You may want to use environment-specific configuration.
Promise.config({
  warnings: {
    wForgottenReturn: false
  }
});

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources')
    .plugin('aurelia-validation');

  aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance) => {
      // register backend plugin
      instance.i18next.use(XHR);

      // adapt options to your needs (see http://i18next.com/docs/options/)
      instance.setup({
        backend: {                                  
          loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
        lng : 'en',
        ns: ['translation'],
        defaultNS: 'translation',
        attributes : ['t','i18n'],
        fallbackLng : 'en',
        debug : false
      });
    });

  // Straight from Aurelia Documentation
  const i18n = aurelia.container.get(i18n);
  ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getMessage = function(key) {
    const translation = i18n.tr(`errorMessages.${key}`);
    return this.parser.parseMessage(translation);
  };

  // Straight from Aurelia Documentation
  ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getDisplayName = function(propertyName) {
    return i18n.tr(propertyName);
  };

  if (environment.debug) {
    aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
  }

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-testing');
  }

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

The error I get is `vendor-bundle.js:3394 Error: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?(…)`

If I delete the two sections marked `// Straight from Aurelia Documentation`, it works fine (but only in one language).

If you see an error in my code, please point it out.  Or, if you have a working example using aurelia-validation and aurelia-i18n working together, please pass on a link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the imported I18N instead:

```
const i18n = aurelia.container.get(I18N);
```

But indeed, i18n seems to stop working afterward. My solution was to update the i18n singleton instance in the first page (app.js), the first time it gets injected:

```
  constructor(i18n) {
    this.i18n = i18n;
    this.initAureliaSingletons();
  }

  /**
   * Some configurations breaks in 'main.js'
   * singletons can be configure here
   * @return {void}
   */
  initAureliaSingletons() {
    const i18n = this.i18n;
    ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getMessage = function(key) {
      const translation = i18n.tr(`validation-${key}`);
      return this.parser.parseMessage(translation);
    };
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.  It does, indeed, correct that bug (which was necessary) but doesn't get i18n and validation working together.  In fact, the immediate result is that i18n stops working in the whole app.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I already have a config.js that I'm using for singletons.  But is it necessary to put this particular i18n singleton in app.js due to the loading feature?  Which loads first -- app.js or main.js?  If I use your model of putting these in App, how do I access these singletons in other components?

Comment: You can access your i18n singleton later by aurelia injection like @inject(I18n). App.js is loaded first but it seems that container.get(I18N) would create another instance instead of a singleton

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this issue as well.  It appears that the line

```
// Straight from Aurelia Documentation
const i18n = aurelia.container.get(i18n);
```

is getting (or more likely creating) a different instance of `i18n` than the

```
aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance) =>
```

I fixed this by getting the `i18n` instance directly from the `aurelia.use.plugin()` as follows (this is typescript but same principle applies to pure js):

```
let i18n:I18N = null;
aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance:I18N) => {
    i18n = instance;
    //rest of plugin code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put it on my main and it works. I think that the trick was to use the variable that was initialized in the plug-in initialization:

```
  var i18n;
  aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance) => {
      // register backend plugin
      instance.i18next.use(Backend.with(aurelia.loader)).use(LngDetector);
      i18n = instance;
```

(...)

```
      aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-validation');

      var standardGetMessage = ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getMessage;
      ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getMessage = function (key) {
          if (i18n.i18next.exists(key)) {
              const translation = i18n.tr(key);
               return this.parser.parse(translation);
          } else {
              return standardGetMessage(key);
          }
      };

      ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getDisplayName = function (propertyName, displayName) {
          if (displayName !== null && displayName !== undefined) {
              return displayName;
          }
          return i18n.tr(propertyName);
      };
```